# Django & Postgres: DB delivers None instead of ""

Tags: django, postgresql

I am migrating a Django website from 1.8 to 2.0.
Also Postgres-DB is upgraded from v8 to v9.

I have a model defined like this:

```
class CMSMailTemplates(models.Model):
  email_cc = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u"Email cc:")

temp = CMSMailTemplates.objects.get(id=1)
```

In the old world if the DB field was empty:

> temp.email_cc == ""

Now after migration if the field is empty

> temp.email_cc is None

Can anybody help me with an explanation?
Is there a way to get "" instead of None for these attributes?

Comment: Why do you set `null=True` in the first place then? I find it rather strange to have two values that both usually represent "emptiness".

Comment: I dont know. I did not code it. I need to migrate it. Can I remove null=True? But will it help with the existing DB?

Comment: Keep `null=False` thats it.